# Is there a Leiningen plugin that provides Git info?

Tags: git, clojure, leiningen

I want to generate a `version.clj` file containing some information cleaned from my project's git repository so that my application's health check can display the following information:

- Git revision
- Git date
- Git author

There is an excellent Maven plugin called [Mavanagaiata](https://github.com/koraktor/mavanagaiata) that does just this, but I haven't found anything like it for Leiningen (i.e. with Google searches for such things as ["leiningen git info"](https://www.google.com/search?q=leiningen+git+info), ["leiningen git plugin"](https://www.google.com/search?q=leiningen+git+plugin), etc.).

I can certainly write my own plugin, if it comes to that, but I hope that this particular wheel has already been invented. :)

Comment: did you look at clj-jgit? https://github.com/clj-jgit/clj-jgit

Comment: clj-jgit is not a Leiningen plugin.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I clearly stated my requirements and the sorts of Google searches I had done by way of research. Please explain how I can improve the quality of this question and I'll happily edit it. Drive-by downvotes don't help anyone.

Comment: explain why you need a leiningen plugin not library or just bash script

Comment: Question edited to address why I want a Leiningen plugin.

Comment: I think it would help if you wrote this up as a problem that you are trying to solve with a lein plugin that cannot be solved at all or as well with some other solution. I don't post questions in SO that are not an encapsulated problem statement with a question that asks how to solve the problem and some proof that I've tried to solve the problem. I voted you up, because your question seemed legit to me with proof that you had gone out and researched.

Comment: clj-jgit could be used to write this plugin, though it's not a solutions in it's self.

Comment: @Arthur : Agreed. I ended up going a simpler route, as per my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

As there does not seem to be an existing Leiningen plugin to do what I want, I decided to extend [lein-git-version](https://github.com/jmglov/lein-git-version), which already writes a `version.clj` file, albeit containing only the version resolved from an annotated git tag.

In case anyone is interested, you can look on Github at the [code that extracts the info I want from the local git repo](https://github.com/jmglov/lein-git-version/blob/master/src/leiningen/git_version.clj), and the [middleware that writes it to `version.clj`](https://github.com/jmglov/lein-git-version/blob/master/src/lein_git_version/plugin.clj).

I decided not to use clj-jgit, as the plugin that I extended used the git command line, and that was good enough for me. If someone wants to use this on a platform where the git CLI isn't available, pull requests are always welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Leiningen plugin [lein-git-info](https://github.com/hilsonchang2018/lein-git-info), which generate project and it's checkouts linked projects git information to version.txt file, the version file also can be packaged in your project jar or war.